# Mobile Calendar Event creation having attendee roll up to contact object

Tags: event, calendar

I have in issue where on the desktop version my org event creation allows the idea for attendees to roll up into the contacts object. But it does not do this action in Mobile version and was wondering if anyone knew a solution for this.

thank you :)